# Automapper - map to Interface type property without creating concrete class

Tags: c#, interface, proxy, automapper

I want to be able to map to IFoo.IBar.Name **without** creating concrete object of type IBar myself.
It's easy to do with proxy at CreateMap level: `Mapper.CreateMap<Person, IFoo>()`, but how to achieve it for custom inner interface type members ?

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void MapToInnerInterface()
    {
        const int id = 1;
        const string name = "Peter";
        var person = new Person {Id = id, Name = name};

        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, IFoo>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar.Name, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Name));

        var mapResult = Mapper.Map<IFoo>(person);

        Assert.Equal(id, mapResult.Id);
        Assert.Equal(name, mapResult.Bar.Name);
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    IBar Bar { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by mapping the outer class (`Person`) to the inner interface (`IBar`), and then leveraging that map in the `Person` → `IFoo` map.

```csharp
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, IFoo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

Mapper.CreateMap<Person, IBar>();

IFoo foo = Mapper.Map<IFoo>(person);

Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar.Name); // Peter
Console.WriteLine(foo.Id); // 1
```

Two proxy objects are created, one implementing `IFoo` and the other implementing `IBar`, as you'd expect.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/VuyT1K

Comment: This is the answer is was looking for - cannot upvote yet. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to map to IFoo.IBar.Name without creating concrete object of type IBar myself

And how do you expect AutoMapper to know what concrete type to use for the `IBar` interface? As you know you cannot have an instance of an interface. And somebody has to specify which is this concrete type and that's definitely not something AutoMapper is capable of doing.

You should use a custom resolver on the `IBar` type or the `AfterMap` option so that you indicate how this mapping should be done.